# Encrypting and decrypting sample with ruby and openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, stdout

i'm trying to do a sample app, for testing purposes vs other people development, and would like to print to the screen the encrypted string, and put it back to a decrypt mechanism....I just don't seem to be finding the way to do this...I've tried base64 and unpack, and feel this is the way, but am not getting there.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def ask(prompt)
    loop do
        print prompt, ' '
        $stdout.flush
        s = gets
        return s.chomp
    end    
end

def aes(m,k,t)
(aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc').send(m)).key = Digest::SHA256.digest(k)
aes.update(t) << aes.final
end

def encrypt(key, text)
aes(:encrypt, key, text)
end

def decrypt(key, text)
aes(:decrypt, key, text)
end


def my_decrypt
 @crypted = ask("Crypted data: ") 
 decrypted = decrypt("12345678911131511192123252729412",@crypted) 
 print decrypted
end

def my_encrypt
 @decrypted = ask("Data to encrypt: ") 
 crypted = encrypt("12345678911131511192123252729412",@decrypted) 
 print crypted
end


option=ask("Option 1 - Encrypt, 2 decrypt")
case option
    when "1" then my_encrypt
    when "2" then my_decrypt
    else print "Option not valid"
end
```

Anyone to the rescue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fight, i finally got it...I just need to convert the binary to Hex, and then back to binary...

Two notes : to convert a binary to hex, you can use [String.unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack), which will return an array.
To convert an hex to binary, you first need to build it as an array ["anystringhere"] , and then pack it back to binary using [Array.pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack)

Here is the resulting code

```rb
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def ask(prompt)
  loop do
    print prompt, ' '
    $stdout.flush
    s = gets
    return s.chomp
  end
end

def aes(m,k,t)
  (aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc').send(m)).key = Digest::SHA256.digest(k)
  aes.update(t) << aes.final
end

def encrypt(key, text)
  aes(:encrypt, key, text)
end

def decrypt(key, text)
  aes(:decrypt, key, text)
end


def my_decrypt
  @crypted = ask("Crypted data: ")
  decrypted = decrypt("12345678911131517192123252729313",[@crypted].pack('H*'))
  print decrypted
end

def my_encrypt
  @decrypted = ask("Data to encrypt: ")
  crypted = encrypt("12345678911131517192123252729313",@decrypted)
  print u=crypted.unpack('H*')
end


option=ask("Option 1 - Encrypt, 2 decrypt")
case option
when "1" then my_encrypt
when "2" then my_decrypt
else print "Option not valid"
end
```